# Queueing ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Trying to make a "queue manager", but I can't quite wrap my head around on how to accomplish this. I realize I can simply disable `async`, but that blocks everything and I need some things to trigger.

My idea is to use callbacks or anything to signal the queue manager that you can let another item through. I have attempted it multiple times and just can't get it quite right.

This is how I imagine it:

```
mc.queueManager = function(ajaxRequest) {
  var queue = []; // The "queue", an array

  this.request = ajaxRequest;
  queue.push(this.request);

  this.curtask = queue.shift() // Grab and remove the first item from the queue

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "handler.php",
    data: {"data": this.curtask},
    success: function(data) {
      // Handle data retrieved
    },
    complete: function() {
      // So, request completed, now this is the callback
      if (queue.length > 0) {
        mc.queueManager(queue.shift()); // Grab next item and repeat
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Right now I can understand nothing is preventing multiple requests from firing, I can't figure out how to do that right now. I'm currently looking into `$.deferred` in the documentation. I also tried a different method using `$.when()` / `.then()`, but to no avail.

Comment: Is the method you posted the same method that is adding requests to the queue? I would have written this a different way where the `queue` isn't being passed to the queuemanager, instead it's stored elsewhere so that more requests can be added to it while the queuemanager is processing the queue.

Comment: @KevinB Yes and separating them is a good idea! I've been working too much, missing the simplest things. Thanks, I will try it a tad different this time.